# Create list with named objects in R and retrieve parts of the objects from this list

Tags: r, list

I have several dataframes (full data and reducted data) and now I want to do a whole lot of analysing with kmeans and hclust. I want to be able to work in a loop and store the results in a list where I can retreive (parts of) the stored objects based on their names. The reason is that in R-Markdown there is no good way to create new objects (and no, assign is NOT a good option to do so).
So the idea is that I make several kmeans-objects in a for-loop on several dataframes and put them to a list. But I can't seem to store them in such a way, that I can name these objects. In my list everything is cluttering up. See my example.
To retreive (parts of) the object of the desired list, I have problems how to address this parts (see my last part)

```
set.seed(4711)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:6, 120, replace = TRUE), ncol = 15, nrow = 8))
list_of_kmeans_objects <- list()

for (i in 2:4){
  list_of_kmeans_objects <- c(list_of_kmeans_objects, kmeans(df, centers = i))
}
```

Now I have a clutterded up list of 36 items. But what I want is a list with 'items' which I also want to be named. My desired list would be:

```
C2_kmeans_df <- kmeans(df, centers = 2)
C3_kmeans_df <- kmeans(df, centers = 3)
C4_kmeans_df <- kmeans(df, centers = 4)
desired_list_of_kmeans <- list(C2_kmeans_df, C3_kmeans_df, C4_kmeans_df, C5_kmeans_df)
names(desired_list_of_kmeans)[1] <- "C2_kmeans_df"
names(desired_list_of_kmeans)[2] <- "C3_kmeans_df"
names(desired_list_of_kmeans)[3] <- "C4_kmeans_df"
```

If I should have this list, my last problem is how do I extract for example

```
C3_kmeans_df$cluster #or
C4_kmeans_df$tot.withinss
```

from this list, using the names of the objects in the desired list?

Comment: If any of the answers solves your problem please consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) / upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `lapply` and `setNames`.

```
idx <- 2:4
out <- setNames(object = lapply(idx, function(i) kmeans(df, centers = i)),
                nm = paste0("C", idx, "_kmeans_df"))
```

Check the names

```
names(out)
# [1] "C2_kmeans_df" "C3_kmeans_df" "C4_kmeans_df"
```

Access `cluster`

```
out$C2_kmeans_df$cluster
# [1] 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your present for loop, you erase the `list_of_kmeans_objects` object at each iteration.

The following code should do what you do want:

```
list_of_kmeans_objects <- list()
aaa <- 0
for (i in 2:4) {
   aaa <- aaa+1
   list_of_kmeans_objects[[aaa]] <- kmeans(df, centers=i)
   names(list_of_kmeans_objects)[aaa] <- paste0("C", aaa, "_kmeans_df")
}
```